# Variable declaration in recursion function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I spent a long time trying to complete this function only to see that the syntax i was trying was not being accepted.

The countSheep function in code academy tells you to complete the function and gives you a newNumber variable that seems to not be defined in the local scope. So I tried to give it the "var" keyword. For some reason I can't understand  the var keyword was not necessary and in order to complete the function and get it to pass the test I had to use the following:

as opposed to defining the variable I just used
newNumber = number -1; // can also be written as newNumber -= 1;
passed newNumber to the function

OR

not defined the newNumber variable and just invoke the function using n-1 as the parameter.

Here is the code that code academy gave us to solve.

```js
function countSheep(number) {
  if (number === 0) {
    console.log("Zzzzzz");// Put your base case here
  } else {
 console.log("Another sheep jumps over the fence.");
 // Define the variable newNumber as 
 // 1 less than the input variable number
 newNumber = number - 1;
 // Recursively call the function
 // with newNumber as the parameter
 countSheep(newNumber);
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell me why the var keyword is not necessary inside of the function to define the newNumber variable. I appreciate it.

Comment: `can also be written as newNumber -= 1` - no it can't

Comment: you can just do `countSheep(number -1);` and forget newNumber altogether

Comment: to answer your question, without the `var` it's equivalent to creating a global variable, i.e. like `window.newNumber = number - 1`

Comment: Also note that omitting the `var` token is forbidden in strict-mode javascript.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Why would we need to create a global variable at this point? We don't need any other function to access the code we just need countSheep to access the variable when its running.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the correction.  and thanks for the explanation. Under what circumstances would it be better to create a global variable as opposed to a local one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newNumber` is a global variable that means, it is assigned to the global object. In browsers this is the `window` object:

```js
function f(x) {
  y = x;
}

console.log(window.y);
f(123);
console.log(window.y);
```

To create a local variable that is only accessible within the function, use `var`:

```js
function f(x) {
  var y = x;
  console.log("within f:", y);
}

f(123);
console.log("outside f:", window.y);
```

To create a local variable that is only accessible within its surrounding block, use `let` or `const`:

```js
function f(x) {
  {
    let y = x;
    console.log("inside block", y);
  }

  try {y} catch (e) {console.log("outside block:", e.message)}
}

f(123);
```

Answer (score 2):

> if you declare **newNumber** using **var** it is only accessable on
>   the scope of 
>   **else block**
>
> .But if you don`t use **var** it will not be
>   local,means can be accessed on the outer scope**(countSheep).**

Comment: in most browsers, that's almost correct - I believe declaring with `var` makes the variable function scoped, not block scoped ... using `let` instead of `var` would make it block scoped as you say ... not using either will make it global scoped, not just "outer" .. equivalent to `window.newNumber = ...`

Comment: Are you citing anything? If no, then don't use blockquotes, if yes then please attribute the source.